# Determine whether any permutation of a given array such that the sum of all subarrays of length K are equal

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview.

> You are given an array consisting of N integers. You need to determine whether any permutation of a given array exists such that the sum of all subarrays of length K are equal. N is divisible by K i.e. N mod K = 0.
>   If the array is [1,2,1,3,2,3] and K = 2, it is False.
>   If the array is [1,2,1,3,2,3] and K = 3, it is True.

My logic was this.

> 1) If N == K, return True.
>   2) Else store each of the distinct element in the array in a dictionary. If the number of distinct elements in the dictionary is greater than K, return False.
>   3) Else store the count of each distinct element in the dictionary.
>   4) If the count of any distinct element is less than (N/K), return False.
>   5) Finally return True.

Here is my code in Python:

```
def check(nums, n, k):
if n == k:
    return True
else:
    my_dict = {}
    for i in nums:
        if i not in my_dict:
            my_dict[i] = 1
        else:
            my_dict[i] += 1
    if len(my_dict) > k:
        return False
    count = int(n/k)
    for i,j in my_dict.items():
        if j < count:
            return False
    return True
```

Am I doing the right approach ? Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Does your code work?  Does it give the correct answers for examples you've tried?

Comment: Yes, it works for the sample cases.

Comment: Since your code works, perhaps you should post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you're looking for feedback.

Comment: ` If N == K, return True.` really? How does it work for your example with K=6?

Comment: In the case of N = K, each subarray of length K i.e. N would contain all the elements in N. In that case, their sum would also be equal since each one contains the same elements.

Comment: Equal to what??? Perhaps I didn't understand this problem. In my understanding `[1,2,3,4] with k=2` has solution `[1,4,   2,3]` (2 subarrays with equal sums=5)

Comment: @MBo We need to consider each subarray of length K.  Also, by definition, the indexes in a subarray need to be contiguous. [1,4] is not a subarray.

Comment: What's about `any permutation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct. The thing is, that element counts need to be divisible by `n / k`.

## Proof

Let's assume that we are given a permutation that meets the criteria. For any distinct element, it's easy to observe, that if it is found in that permutation at `i`, it must be also found, at: `i - k, i - 2k,... ,i mod k` and `i + k, i + 2k,.., n - k + (i mod k)`, hence occurrence at `i` implies implies occurrence at `i % k < k`. Now, each distinct occurrence at position with index lower than `k` implies `n / k` occurrences in total (here the fact that `n mod k = 0` is crucial).

### Counter example for OP`s solution

An example which would break you solution (almost surely minimal):

> n = 8, k = 4
> array = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: Thanks @paler123. I understood where I got it wrong.